# How can I stop Friendcaster automatically attempting to upload every picture taken on my Samsung Galaxy S2 running Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, facebook, photos

Every time I take a photo on my Samsung Galaxy S2 it then prompts me to Save or Delete the photo, and then a Friendcaster prompt asks me to give the photo a name to upload it to Facebook. While this could be useful in some situations, I do not want every photo I take to upload, and the only way I can seem to get out of uploading the photo is by closing the Take Photo app. This is obviously a little frustrating when trying to take multiple pictures. 
I cannot seem to find any setting within the Take Photo app or within Friendcaster to prevent this. I currently back up all of my photos to Picasa where by default the photos are marked as private.